# Как расположить блок поверх границы двух блоков?

Tags: css3, html5

Нужно расположить блок video так, чтобы он заезжал на блок info на 50px.
Пробовала с помощью свойств height и overflow: visible, но это способ оказался ошибочным.

```css
.video__iframes {
  height: 316px;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.video__iframe {
  width: 515px;
  height: 316px;
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 160px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<section class="video">
  <div class="video__iframes">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/arj7oStGLkU" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="video__iframe"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5MgBikgcWnY" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen class="video__iframe"></iframe>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="info">
</section>
```

Comment: макет есть ? скрин того что требуется ?

Comment: а вообще наверно отрицательным margin-botom - должно сработать